# How do I Check For Any Value of an Array in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array

```
var fileExtension = [".gif", ".png", ".jpg"];
```

I understand I can check if the array value contains a value X, Y or Z. but that's not what I'm looking to achieve.

I have a second variable

```
var Extension;
```

and a third

```
var selectorString = "a[href$=" + "\"" + Extension  + "\"" + "\]";
```

Now I want

```
var Extension = (any value of the Array FileExtension).
```

could be anything so long as it's a value of the `FileExtension`.

Comment: Can you paste a code to clarify the understanding?

Comment: so if you know you can check if the array contains a value, what's your problem?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you want to select a random element from `fileExtension`? Or do you want to find all `a` elements that have any of the extensions?

Comment: I think he want to find if a value is in a array, he can use jQuery inArray for this like I said below

Comment: var fileExtension = [".gif", ".png", ".jpg"];
 var AnyMemberOfFileExtension = fileExtension[0] or fileExtension[1] or fileExtension[2];
 var selectorString = "a[href$=" + "\"" + AnyMemberOfFileExtension  + "\"" + "\]";

Comment: So, you want a random value from the array then?

Comment: Yes, I want to find if the value is the array then assign that value to the variable var Extension;

Comment: then, No, you don't want a random value, you just want to make sure the value is one of the values in the array? you're not making much sense... *"Yes, I want to find if the value is the array"* is contradictory

Comment: "then, No, you don't want a random value, you just want to make sure the value is one of the values in the array? you're not making much sense.."  Yes Kevin that's excatly what I want.. Make sure it's one of the values of the array. and assign just that one value to the var Extension.

Comment: you will have to use commas in a fairly repetitive selector, since CSS has no OR for attribs

Comment: I see. you're building a selector string, that matches all of those extensions. The only thing in the question that points to that conclusion is the name of a variable in a code snippet... maybe make that clearer?

Comment: Thanks Dandavis. that's exactly what I did, buh was looking for a more dynamic solution here's what i did: $("a[href$=".jpg"], a[href$=".png"], a[href$=".gif"]").doSomething();  but what if we had 1million file extensions?

Comment: then you would have a really long querystring and would likely push the limits of document.querySelectorAll. either way you will need a selector string in that format, whether you generate it by hand or from an array.

Comment: phew!! Thanks @Kevin B and all. Tot I could do it dynamically say by adding the file extensions to an array then looping through the array. Arrrghhh!!!

Comment: well, you can. jsut loop over the array, and for each extension, append `a[href$=".png"]` to a string.

Comment: Could you please explain via code sample..? pretty pls..?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, just loop over the array to create the really long selector string.

```
var fileExtensions = [".gif", ".png", ".jpg"];
var selectorString = fileExtensions.map(function (ext) {
  return 'a[href$="' + ext + '"]';
}).join(',');
$(selectorString).addClass('image');
```

Comment: Excellent Kevin. but here's the very obvious problem I've been trying to solve : when I do a console.log(selectorString); from your code above; I get this: a[href$=".gif"]a[href$=".png"]a[href$=".jpg"]. which is not a valid selector. is there a way to choose just one of those 3 options as long as it's valid?

Comment: Yes, use an array and a join with commas.

Comment: How Kevin? Pardon me I'm a jquery novice .

Comment: well... it's in my answer.

Comment: You nailed it Kevin. Wooorrrrkked!!!!! sorry I didn't realise you'd updated your answer. you're a Genius, man. Thanks alot for you time, patience and expertise.